# React: How to combine each multiple styles marked in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, material-ui

I have two styles.

One thing is included in specific components, another thing is included in global components.

for example, let's suppose that we have the following tree.

```
index.tsx
-App.tsx
-globalConstants.ts
```

in globalConstants.ts

```
import { Theme, makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const sharedStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    .
    .
    .
  }),
);
```

in App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Theme, makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { sharedStyles } from '../constants/globalConstants'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    .
    .
    .
  }),
);
```

My problem is I can't combine useStyles and sharedStyles into one classes variable.

Of course, I can use this like following

```
export default function NavBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const sharedClasses = sharedStyles();
}
```

But I'd like to combine classes and sharedClasses into one constants such as

```
const classes = {useStyles()+sharedStyles())
```

Is there some good way how to combine that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it seems to lead us to an open-based answer, still, I'd like to provide some approach that I have found.

Refer to material-ui official document: [styles_advanced](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles-withstyles-styled)

You can use third-party libs like **clsx**.

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStylesBase = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: 'blue', // 
  },
});

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: 'red', // 
  },
});

export default function MyComponent() {
  // Order doesn't matter
  const classes = useStyles();
  const classesBase = useStylesBase();

  // Order doesn't matter
  const className = clsx(classes.root, classesBase.root)

  // color: red  wins.
  return <div className={className} />;
}
```

I'm sure there are many similar libs so choose the one you feel good about.

And you can implement it by yourself, refer to the sample in [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11517)

```
function combineStyles(...styles) {
  return function CombineStyles(theme) {
    const outStyles = styles.map((arg) => {
      // Apply the "theme" object for style functions.
      if (typeof arg === 'function') {
        return arg(theme);
      }
      // Objects need no change.
      return arg;
    });

    return outStyles.reduce((acc, val) => Object.assign(acc, val));
  };
}

export default combineStyles;
```

Hope this answer would find you well.

Comment: OMG, This is exactly what I want. Thank you for great answer and perfect solution!!
Excuse me, but could you tell me what the meaning of '...styles' is in react?

Comment: @SteveBack It's so called [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in javascript