# Material-UI, how to merge multiple styles with theme in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, themes

I have two styles.

in global.ts

```
const globalStyles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return {
    g: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(40),
    },
  }
}

export const mergedStyle = (params: any) => makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    ...globalStyles,
    ...params
  }),
);
```

in App.tsx

```
import * as Global from './global';

const localStyles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return {
    l: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(20),
    },
  }
}

export default function DenseAppBar() {
  const classes = Global.mergedStyle(localStyles)();

  return (
    <div>
      <MenuIcon className={classes.l} />
      <MenuIcon className={classes.g} />
      <MenuIcon />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It doesn't have any compile error, but it doesn't work.
How should I modify my code?

I added codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hamilton-6eect

Comment: So, what error do you get?

Comment: @SagarMore
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Record<"a", string>' and 'Record<"b", string>'.ts(2365)

Comment: @keikai Yes. But I've even changed ts into js, but that doesn's work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a common `makeStyles` to generate the inner content with [spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) would be fine.

```
const style1 = (theme) => {
  return {
    a: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    }
  }
}
const style2 = (theme) => {
  return {
    b: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    }
  }
}
const mergedStyle = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    ...style1(theme),
    ...style2(theme),
  }),
);
```

Usage

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const classes = mergedStyle();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.a}></div>
      <div className={classes.b}></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Try it online:

[image: Edit friendly-goldstine-t5dhj]

---

#### Update

If you want to pass params in `mergeStyle` function

```
const mergedStyle = (params) =>makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    ...
  }),
);
```

usage

```
const classes = mergedStyle(params)();
```

---

Related question: [how-to-combine-each-maked-styles-in-material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714277/how-to-combine-each-maked-styles-in-material-ui/60715368#60715368)

Comment: I really appreciate your sincere answer. ありがとうございます(Arigatou gozaimasu)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.
If you are okay, could you see my source?
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hamilton-6eect

Comment: `...globalStyles(theme)`, you forgot the `(theme)` https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mestorf-yl06p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark